# Angular - Exclude div from focusout

Tags: html, angular, input, focusout

This span is located within the input field. I would like to exaclude the span from the input's focusout event. any ideas?

```
<input type="text" (focusin)="onFocusIn($event)" (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)"/>
  <span (mousedown)="onClearClick()"></span>
```